# Backbone partial view not rendering the latest model

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backbone-views

I am relatively new to Backbone and I am running into this problem.

I am using Backbone with DustJS

My template looks something like this - `index.dust`

```
<div id="parentView">
  <div class="section">
    {>"app/inc/responseMessage" /}
    <div class="userDetails">
      {! A button to get user details !}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my partial below - `responseMessage.dust`

```
<div id="responseMessage">
  {@eq key="{data.success}" value="true"}
    <div class="alert alert-success success" role="alert">success</div>
  {/eq}
</div>
```

My JS looks like this

```
initialize: function() {
    this.responseMessageView = this.responseMessageView ||
        new ResponseMessageView({
            model: new Backbone.Model()
        }); // View is for the partial
    this.model = this.model || new Backbone.Model(); //View for the whole page
},
```

Below function is called when an event occurs and it does a POST and returns successfully.

```
primaryViewEventTrigger: function(event){
  //Button click on `index.dust` triggers this event and does a POST event to the backend

  this.listenToOnce(this.model, 'sync', this.primaryViewSuccess);//this will render the whole view. 
  this.listenToOnce(this.model, 'error', this.primaryViewError);
  this.model.save({data: {x:'123'}});
}

responseViewEventTrigger: function(event){
  //Button click on `responseMessage.dust` triggers this event and does a POST event to the backend

  this.listenToOnce(this.responseMessageView.model, 'sync', this.responseViewSuccess);//it should only render the partial view - responseMessage.dust
  this.listenToOnce(this.responseMessageView.model, 'error', this.primaryViewError);
  this.responseMessageView.model.save({data: {x:'123'}});
}
primaryViewSuccess: function(model,response){
    this.model.set('data', response.data);
    this.render();
}
responseViewSuccess: function(model,response){
    this.responseMessageView.model.set('data', response.data);
    console.log(this.responseMessageView.model);
    this.responseMessageView.render(); // Does not work in some cases
}
```

My implementations of the callback function

```
exports.sendEmail = function sendEmail(req, res){
  req.model.data.success = true;
  responseRender.handleResponse(null, req, res);
};
```

`this.model` belongs to the model of the whole page. Whereas `this.responseMessageView.model` is the model for the partial.

Question: This works perfectly fine in most of the cases. There is one case where it does not render the partial with the latest model values. When I click on the button on `index.dust` and `primaryViewSuccess` is executed. After which I click on another button and trigger `responseViewEventTrigger`. It does the POST successfully and it comes to `responseViewSuccess` and stores it in the model too. But it does not show it on the frontend. `data.success` is still not true whereas `console.log(this.responseMessageView.model)` show that `attributes->data->success = true`

But the same behavior when I refresh the page it all works perfect. Its just that when `primaryViewSuccess` is called and then `responseViewSuccess` its not taking the latest model changes. *In other words model is being updated but the DOM remains the same.*

What am I missing here? Thanks for your time!

Comment: Are you intentionally passing new model to `responseMessageView ` or are you expecting the model you're referring to in this code to be same..? You seems to be doing `this.model.set('data', response.data);` `this.responseMessageView.model.set('data', response.data);` etc and looks like a mess... We don't know what is the *thing* containing the `initialize` in first code block... We don't know what is the *thing* containing the second code block.. you might want to explain the relationships between these views, models etc first

Comment: @t-j I have edited the question. I do not understand what do you mean by thing? initialize() is used to declare a view for the whole page and for the partial. Sorry if I am not able to explain myself well.

Comment: By *thing* I was asking whether it's a view, collection etc... I didn't get what you mean by "*Its just that when primaryViewSuccess is called and then responseViewSuccess its not taking the latest model changes."* which view is not taking which model changes..? You have 2 views and 2 models. Please explain based on that, who should update based on whom.

Comment: One thing I don't understand is the reason for having separate models for both views... they seems to be using the same data `this.model.set('data', response.data);`... If you use thee same model then it'll be easier to keep both view in sync. Also, you don't have to manually set `response.data` into model. You can return `response.data` from `parse` method, it'll be set automatically.

Comment: show me how your POST callback is written please

Comment: @FrançoisRichard My Post function looks like this
    ```exports.sendEmail = function sendEmail(req, res){

 callsomefunction(req, function(err, response){
   req.model.data.success = true;
   responseRender.handleResponse(null, req, res);
       });
};```

Comment: @TJ I use the same model too. It still gives me the same error. `responseViewSuccess: function(model,response){
    this.model.set('data', response.data);
    this.responseMessageView.render(); // Does not work in some cases
}` .. This still does not work :(

Comment: @TJ Answering the first question - There are 2 events occurring. One should trigger the `primaryViewSuccess` and the other `responseViewSuccess`. Each of them have their own models and views which needs to be updated. Now if I trigger responseViewSuccess it works perfectly fine. But when I trigger `primaryViewSuccess` followed by the `responseViewSuccess` it does not work.

Comment: but how do you use it and update your model that's what I needf

Comment: also where is the ajaxcall ? I need to see how you wrote the ajax call not only the callback

Comment: @FrançoisRichard `this.model.save()` does the POST request.(this is the ajaxcall)  `this.responseMessageView.model.set('data', response.data);` this updates the model and `this.responseMessageView.render()` should render the view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're hitting the classic Backbone render-with-subviews gotcha: When you render the index view, you are replacing *all* of the DOM nodes. That includes the DOM node that your `responseMessageView` instance is tied to. If you inspect the `responseMessageView.el` you'll actually see that it has been updated with the new model data, however the element isn't attached to the index's DOM tree anymore.

```
var Parent = Backbone.View.extend({
  template: _.template(''),
  render: function() {
    this.$el.html(this.template());
  },

  initialize: function() {
    this.render();
    this.child = new Child();
    this.$el.append(child.el);
  }
});
```

Here when you manually call render, `child.el` will no longer be in the 
`parent.el` (you can check using the inspector).

The simplest fix here is to call `child.setElement` after the parent renders with the newly rendered `div#responseMessage` element. The better fix is to detach the `responseMessageView`'s element beforehand, and reattach after:

```
var Parent = Backbone.View.extend({
  render: function() {
    this.responseMessageView.$el.detach();
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    this.$el.find('#responseMessage').replaceWith(this.responseMessageView.el);
  }
});
```

Comment: This makes absolutely sense. But since I am using DustJS this does not work for me :/ .. I do `this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));` The parent view does not show the latest model changes. the html does not show the model changes.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use success callback and let me know I think your problem may come from here:

this.model.save( {att1 : "value"}, {success :handler1, error: handler2});

Also are you sure you want to use listenToOnce ? instead of listenTo ??

Comment: Nope this does not work. My function looks like this `this.responseMessageView.model.save({data: {email: emailAddress.val()}});` ..Also I have to mention that the success callback is being fired for sure. As I have console statements in that.

Comment: I tried this `this.responseMessageView.model.save({data: {email: emailAddress.val()}}, {success :this.responseViewSuccess, error: this.responseViewError});` .. This does not work :( what am I missing?

Comment: I did listenTo and still no avail :/

Answer (score 3):

Try doing `this.delegateEvents()` after your render (http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents).